# JSF/Facelets : CSS file is not being recognized using <h:outputStylesheet> tag

Tags: html, css, jsf, facelets

I'm working on a project using JSF/Facelets. I want to do some CSS changes on my View XHTML, but nothing happen when i deploy my web application in my Tomcat Server. I've tried many tricks but i've got the same result.

Anyway, here's my "styles.css" :

```
body { width: 750px; }

#header 
{
width:              100%;
font-size:          36px;
font-weight:        bold;
line-height:        48px;
background-color:   navy;
color:              white;
}

#footer
{
width:              100%;
font-weight:        bold;
background-color:   navy;
color:              white;
}
```

And this is the main template "Template.html" including "Header.html" and "Footer.html", where i put my "styles.css" using the  tag :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css" />
    <!-- i've also tried this one, using the "library" attribute -->
    <!--
     <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css" />
    -->
</head>
<h:body>
<h:panelGroup id="page" layout="block">

    <h:panelGroup id="header" layout="block">
        <ui:insert name="header">
            <ui:include src="Header.html" />
        </ui:insert>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup id="container" layout="block">
        <h:panelGroup id="content" layout="block">
            <ui:insert name="content">CONTENT</ui:insert>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup id="footer" layout="block">
        <ui:insert name="footer">
            <ui:include src="Footer.html" />
        </ui:insert>
    </h:panelGroup>

</h:panelGroup>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Anf finally here's my "Main.xhtml" which include the template "Template.html" :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" template="Template.html">
<h:body>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <h:inputText title="inputText"></h:inputText>
            <h:commandButton value="OK"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</h:body>
 </ui:composition>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can u please verify in your browser that your css has been loaded.

Comment: Rightclick page in browser and *View Source* and/or press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug and check "Network" section.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `<h:outputStylesheet>` (and `<h:outputScript>`) requires a `<h:head>`, but you've there a `<head>`. Fix it accordingly.

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css" />
</h:head>
```

Further, you need to ensure that the `css/styles.css` file is been placed in the `/resources` subfolder of the public webcontent.

```
WebContent
 |-- resources
 |    `-- css
 |         `-- styles.css
 :
```

As to your attempt to use the `library` attribute, be careful with this, using `library="css"` isn't entirely correct in this context. See also: [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: Yes i have checked this before, and i've put my styles.css in the same path as u said :  WebContent/resources/css/styles.css

Comment: In the tree, shouldn't be `WebContent/resources/css/styles.css` instead of `WebContent/resources/css/style.css` ?

Comment: and in case of composition, add the css inside the ui:composition tag

Answer (score -4):

Add **resources** folder under the **WebContent**

and inside resources create css folder

then access the files like this

`h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="myNewStylesFile.css" target="head"`  under `h:head` section that you did not add

Comment: I downvoted because I consider this as spam, it's the same as BalusC's answer with words removed, answered 3 years later.