# How to add a css to PrimeFaces?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I try to add css to PrimeFaces and overwrite the defaults components font size.

My **default.css**:

```
.body {
    font-size: 10%;
}

.ui-widget,.ui-widget-header,.ui-widget-content,.ui-widget-header .ui-widget-header,.ui-widget-content .ui-widget-content,.ui-widget input,.ui-widget select,.ui-widget textarea,.ui-widget button
    {
    font-size: 10%;
}

.button{   
    font-size: 10%;
}

.ui-widget.button{
    font-size: 10%;   
}
```

On the xml body:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css" />
```

and for example I tried to add new css to the button:

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="button" id="add" value="Add" ajax="false"/>
```

What am I doing incorrectly, do not see any effects.

Comment: Check if the css is loaded, check in the **generated html** if your selectors are [specific enough](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) (use a browser developer tool)

Comment: also check if the order of loading of the stylesheets is right

Comment: try using <h:outputStylesheet name="css/default.css" />

Comment: @Eiten, Where is your default.css located? Try icluding it using simple css tag.

Comment: This change helped, but I do not why: <link href="./css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> CSS is located in folder CSS.

Comment: You can also check it by chrome's inspect element feature to check and adjust CSS as you desire

Comment: Where are you defining the `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="default.css" /> `? is it in your `<h:body>` in your jsf page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: Could you also add a view of your project folder tree? The thing is for css file to be processed as a resource it should be located in web/resources folder of your project. See this answer for more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/12282175/4745608

Answer (score -1):

Try removeing `,` from :

```
.ui-widget,.ui-widget-header,.ui-widget-content,.ui-widget-header .ui-widget-header,.ui-widget-content .ui-widget-content,.ui-widget input,.ui-widget select,.ui-widget textarea,.ui-widget button
    {
    font-size: 10%;
}
```

Replace it with this :

```
.ui-widget .ui-widget-header .ui-widget-content .ui-widget-header .ui-widget-header .ui-widget-content .ui-widget-content .ui-widget input .ui-widget select .ui-widget textarea .ui-widget button
    {
    font-size: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Primefaces you can create your own Themes to define components layout. you can copy and change a community theme or create your own with [**Theme Roller**](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

All steps are well explained in the [documentation/User Guides](http://primefaces.org/documentation).

Comment: This is a way to complex solution for just changing font-size and you want to keep all other stuff from the PF theme